# Insert a document into a particular database MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, roxy

I'm setting up a database with roxy, which is different from the "documents" database. I want to insert a config file into that database.

I have this function in xquery ml-1.0

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";



declare namespace appsetup = "http://kittens.com.au/appsetup";



declare function appsetup:setup-day0($root,$content-db){
    (: some values :)
    let $m := map:new ()
    let $_ := map:put ($m, "Kittens-Forever",xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]", "2999-12-31"))
    let $_ := map:put ($m, "Kittens-Never", xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]", "1899-12-31"))
    let $_ := map:put ($m, "Kittens-Load-Root", $root)

    return  xdmp:document-insert ("/ksys/smap", <s:map>{$m}</s:map>,
                    (xdmp:permission ("Kittens-role", "read"),
                    xdmp:permission ("Kittens-role", "update")) )

};
```

The `xdmp:document-insert` inserts the document in to the default "documents" database. I had a look around, and i couldn't find a way to say load this document into this database. I only found a way to insert the document into a particular forest with xdmp:document-load (https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-load).

Is there a way for me to say load this thing into this database, preferably just as a xquery parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xdmp:document-insert does not insert into the Documents database by default. It inserts into the database defined in the application server configuration. The idea is that you have an application server that you use to interface with the database.

Some notes:

- Use an app server configured for your database.
- Or use the REST API that has a parameter for this
- Or use HTTP rewrite rules to dynamically change the database based on a user, URI or query parameter
- Or use xdmp:eval or its derivatives (spawn, invoke, invoke-function) which all have an option to define which database to use.

For your particular sample, I would suggest that you use xdmp:invoke-function.

Comment: I like invoke-function (https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke-function).

Comment: This probably helps:
http://www.xqueryhacker.com/2014/05/01/applying-a-function-in-the-context-of-a-different-database-updated-for-marklogic-7.html

Comment: One note about your link - the official documentation for MarkLogic is updated per release. in ML8, there is a new transaction mode: update-auto-commit that is not available in 7.  In many cases, it is invaluable because if used with isolation=different-transaction, then the inserted document is available in the original calling code.

Comment: Can't we just point to the right database from the config. file itself ? I mean 1st check what database roxy is pointing to by command like `ml local info | grep content-db`. That way we will get to know what is the default db roxy is pointing to. Later just override the configuration at local.properties file and point to the right database. Something like
`content-db=xyz-db` or `app-content-db=xyz-db`. Now just use xdmp:document-insert by overriding roxy function to point to your .xqy file where you have written xdmp:document-insert logic.